# onchange event not being triggered

Tags: php, javascript

I have a simple select option box, the contents of which are generated from a PHP script. I looks like this

```
<form action="php/reloadNewList.php" method="POST">
    <select name="listToGo" onchange="redirect(this.form.value)">
    <?php 
    include('php/getMyList.php');
    getList(); 
    ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

The list generated looks fine

```
<option value="1">Hello</option>
<option value="12">Smelly</option>
etc
```

My JS script is simple enough as well

```
function redirect(value)
{
    var x=value.selectedIndex;
    alert("listToGo="+x + "\nValue = "+value);
    document.cookie = "ListCookie="+x;
    window.location.reload();
}
```

The problem I'm getting is that the onchange is not responding to the change on the drop down list.

Comment: You can use jsFiddle for "plain good ol' JS"....

Comment: could you explain what would be the expected alert message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this -

```
<select name="listToGo" onchange="redirect(this.value);">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
<select name="listToGo" onchange="redirect(this)">
```

And:

```
function redirect(slct)
{
    console.log(slct)
    var x=slct.selectedIndex;
    var value = slct.value;
    alert("listToGo="+x + "\nValue = "+value);
    document.cookie = "ListCookie="+x;
    window.location.reload();
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/YyUwR/1/